Issues Connecting to NATS WebSocket (ws://) in Golang WASM SDK
I’m working on building a client-side SDK that interacts with NATS for both mobile and web. The mobile version is being built using Gomobile, and we’ve successfully connected to the NATS server using nats:// connections without any issues.
// Initialize NATS client, storage, and monitoring
func InitNATS(subject string, natsURL string, ttlHours int) {
    var err error

    opts := []nats.Option{
        nats.Name("Go WebSocket Client"),
        nats.ReconnectWait(2 * time.Second),
        nats.MaxReconnects(10),
        nats.ClosedHandler(func(nc *nats.Conn) {
            fmt.Println("Connection closed")
        }),
        nats.DiscoveredServersHandler(func(nc *nats.Conn) {
            fmt.Println("Discovered new server:", nc.Servers())
        }),
        nats.ReconnectHandler(func(nc *nats.Conn) {
            fmt.Println("Reconnected to:", nc.ConnectedUrl())
        }),
    }

    // Connect to NATS server
    natsClient, err = nats.Connect(natsURL, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to connect to NATS: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Initialize Event Store using localStorage (for WASM)
    eventStore = storage.NewLocalStorageEventStore(time.Duration(ttlHours) * time.Hour)

    // Initialize Event Producer
    eventProducer = events.NewAsyncEventProducer(natsClient, 1000, eventStore, subject)

    // Initialize Event Consumer
    eventConsumer = events.NewAsyncEventConsumer(natsClient, eventStore, subject)

    // Initialize Node Monitor for tracking connected peers and events
    nodeMonitor = monitor.NewNodeMonitor(subject, eventConsumer, eventProducer)
    go nodeMonitor.StartMonitoring(natsClient, natsClient.Opts.Name, 2*time.Second, 4*time.Second)
}

This works with normal golang compilation, but it doesn't work on wasm
    <script src="wasm_exec.js"></script> <!-- Include the Go WASM runtime -->
    <script>
        // Load Go WASM
        const go = new Go();

        let wasmModule;

        WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm"), go.importObject).then(result => {
            go.run(result.instance);
            wasmModule = result.instance;
            console.log("WASM Module loaded.");
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error("Error loading WASM Module: ", err);
        });

        // Function to update output
        function updateOutput(msg) {
            const outputElem = document.getElementById('output');
            outputElem.innerHTML = msg;
        }

        // Initialize NATS
        document.getElementById("initNATSBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
            try {
                initNATS("orderEvents", "ws://127.0.0.1:8080", 24);
                updateOutput("NATS initialized");
            } catch (e) {
                updateOutput("Error initializing NATS: " + e.message);
            }
        }); 

Now, I’m trying to get the same SDK working on the web by compiling the Go code to WebAssembly (WASM). However, I’m running into a problem when trying to connect to the NATS server over WebSocket (ws://). The same setup works perfectly in normal Go code (outside of WASM), but in the WASM-compiled version, the NATS client fails to establish a WebSocket connection.
Additional context:

Mobile version: Working fine with nats:// connections.
Web version (WASM): Fails when trying to connect to ws:// NATS.
Golang code connecting to the server using ws also works fine.
Regular WebSocket connections in WASM: These work fine, so I don’t believe the issue is with WebAssembly’s WebSocket handling in general.
NATS CLI: I can successfully connect to the NATS server over both nats:// and ws:// using the NATS CLI without any issues.

However, when trying to connect via the WASM-compiled version of the SDK, I get the following error message:
 Failed to connect to NATS: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: address 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: Connection refused
This indicates the connection isn’t even reaching the WebSocket layer but is trying to establish a TCP connection instead. Has anyone encountered issues with NATS WebSocket connections in WASM? Is there something specific about how the NATS Go client or WebAssembly handles ws:// that might be causing this?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

127.0.0.1:8080: connect: Connection refused you expect something to be listening at that address / port, but the message is an indication that the port is not open.

Thanks, Erik, but the port is open, as I am able to connect to that port using Nats cli and wscat without any issues.
and the server is running on host 0.0.0.0 so it should be available on all interfaces too.
❯ lsof -i :8080 COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME main    97896 thushar   35u  IPv6 0x2e152c1685b5de8c      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)

Which NATS library are you using? It looks like you are running the code in a browser, these limit the network functionality and standard Go network functions will not work - this may well be the issue.

I am using github.com/nats-io/nats.go v1.37.0 and yes. The  TCP/UDP connections doesn't work with WASM as it runs on a sandbox. That is why I am trying to run using websocket. It seems to connect using websocket to the server when running it normally, but even if I use the same functions, it is not working on WASM as it is trying to Dial using TCP to ws:// address. The library is supposed to automatically connect using websockets. and Normal websocket connections seem to work on WASM as well.

See the issue I linked. You are correct that it is possible to establish a websocket connection from WASM running in a browser, however this must be done in a particular way (example) and, based on that issue, it does not appear that github.com/nats-io/ currently supports this (an alternative library is mentioned in the issue).
